# M-x eval-buffer my init.el file every time I start emacs

Tags: init-file

I am a total emacs newbie. I was following the [Master Emacs in one year](https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/guide-en.org) guide by Chen Bin. Following it, I cloned Steve Purcell's [.emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d) repo.

Now the guide works just fine when I do M-x eval-buffer for my "~/.emacs.d/init.el" file. However, as soon as I restart Emacs, the changes are gone. I have to eval-buffer every time I start emacs.
I also checked some websites which explains me to have either .emacs file or init.el file and not both. But every time I delete my .emacs file, Emacs generates it automatically when I restart it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `~/.emacs` or `~/init.el` files? These would preclude you from using `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as your init file.

Comment: @wvxvw  I do have a `~/.emacs` file. As I mentioned in my question, when I delete it, it appears automatically when I restart Emacs. In addition to that I do also have `~/.emacs.desktop` and `~/.emacs.elc` files.

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you install Emacs? What version?

Comment: An `~/emacs` directory will also interfere.

Comment: Hm... this is odd, well, it must be something in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` which creates that file... That doesn't normally happen on its own.

Comment: @Gilles I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I am using GNU Emacs 24.4.1. I installed it using the following guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: @wdkrnls You are right. I did have a `/emacs` directory. I have now deleted it. The issue still seems to persist.

Comment: @wvxvw I am not sure. I just cloned Steve Purcell's `/.emacs.d` folder. Here is the link to his `/.emacs.d/init.el` : https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init.el . Can you please have a look at it and tell me if something is wrong. Shall I put a screenshot of my `/.emacs.d/init.el` in the question details?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in Steve's config that will create a ~/.emacs file -- that does seem quite strange. If that file is being recreated when you start emacs, what is in it?

Comment: It worked somehow. I don't what I did but when I deleted `.emacs`, `.emacs.desktop` and `.emacs.elc` files as well as `emacs` folder in my home directory, it magically started working as it should be. Also, I updated all installed the packages. Thank You @glucas @wvxvw @Gilles and @wdkrnls . This doesn't explain why `.emacs` was getting automatically created though.

Comment: It was auto-created because it is the default init file.  If it hadn't already been "fixed" I'd've suggested renaming ~/.emacs.d/init.el to ~/.emacs and loading the config that way.  Now, more importantly, are you using a Mac?  If the answer is "no" you should go through that init file you copied and delete all the OS X references.